# Is there any documentation evidence that order of Map keyset converted to List is preserved?

Tags: apex, list, map, set, collection

When we execute a code

```
Map<String, String> tm = new Map<String, String>{
'Monday'=>'\u041f\u043e\u043d\u0435\u0434\u0456\u043b\u043e\u043a',
'Tuesday'=>'\u0412\u0456\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u043e\u043a',
'Wednesday'=>'\u0421\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0434\u0430',
'Thursday'=>'\u0427\u0435\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0440',
'Friday'=>'\u041f\'\u044f\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0446\u044f',
'Saturday'=>'\u0421\u0443\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430',
'Sunday'=>'\u041d\u0435\u0434\u0456\u043b\u044f'};
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + String.join( new List<String>(tm.keySet()), ',') );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + tm.keySet() );
```

the first debug displays correct order

> @@@ v: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday

while the second debug displays incorrect order

> @@@ v: {Friday, Monday, Saturday, Sunday, Thursday, Tuesday, Wednesday}

This means that even despite a keyset is a set and unordered collection, Salesforce remembers the correct order and when you convert this set into list, Salesforce provides correct order.

Is such behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

[Looks like since Summer'15 iteration order for sets and maps is now predictable and these release notes might explain such behavior.](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm)

> The order of elements in unordered collections (Map and Set) is now
>   the same each time your code is run. Previously, the order of elements
>   in unordered collections was arbitrary, and you couldn’t rely on the
>   order of elements in maps and sets. Ideally, you don’t want your code
>   to depend on the order of elements in unordered collections. If you
>   have such code, it could sometimes fail before this change. This
>   change makes your code more robust because the iteration order in maps
>   and sets is always the same.
>
> This example illustrates how the iteration order is deterministic in a
>   map. A map is created with two elements. Next, the for loop iterates
>   over the map elements and writes the key and value of each element to
>   the debug log. Each time you execute this snippet, the iteration order
>   of the elements in the for loop is the same.
>
> ```
> Map<String, String> currencyMap = new Map<String, String>();
> currencyMap.put('France','Euro'); currencyMap.put('Japan', 'Yen');
> // Iterate through the map elements. 
> for (String mapKey : currencyMap.keySet()) {
>             System.debug('Key: ' + mapKey +
>                 ', Value: ' + currencyMap.get(mapKey)); }
>
>         // The output is: Key: France, Value: Euro Key: Japan, Value: Yen
> ```

Comment: The example on the question side might be a little risky because the keys have an inherent order (the days of the week) that Salesforce is *not* guaranteeing to return, as I read this doc. It's guaranteeing *some* deterministic order, not *creation* order, even though that appears to be the current strategy.